# How can I install ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Creating a new React app in G:\reactproject.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall G:\reactproject\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.2 postinstall G:\reactproject\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.2 postinstall G:\reactproject\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- react@16.12.0
- react-dom@16.12.0
- cra-template@1.0.0
- react-scripts@3.3.0
  added 1535 packages from 745 contributors and audited 906206 packages in 180.308s

33 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: When I install via npx create-react-app reactproject show me this and I can't install reactJs. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you already did. Run `npm list react`, if it returns a version you were successful

Comment: Yes return react version. But where the src folder public folder? How can i get app.js  file main.js file

Comment: React is a library not a framework. You have to create all of the folder structure yourself. React doesn't require it or create it for you. Create-react-app is what does that for you. If its not working the problem is with CRA not react

Comment: If you look inside of `G:\reactproject` you don't see anything?

Comment: I am new in reactJs. So I have no Knowledge to create those folder structure. How can i get those file. Can you help me?

Comment: What was the path in your command prompt when you used "create-react-app reactproject"?

Comment: This was my path  G:\npx create-react-app reactproject

Comment: So you have change path to `G:` first before running `npx create-react-app reactproject`?

Comment: No No. C:\Users\Abhijit Paul> This was the path. Then I changed my path to G: and run npx create-react-app reactproject

Comment: What is inside the `reactproject` folder right now?

Comment: `node_modules` folder, `package.json` file & `package-lock.json` file

Comment: After reading all the valuable comments, I am guessing that the question could be that create-react-app command couldn't generate the complete file structure.
If thats the case,
Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708568/create-react-app-only-creates-node-modules-package-and-package-lock/61708736#61708736)!

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion in this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8278) from the official [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/) github, you can just run the same command but with the `--ignore-existing` flag added and it should re-install your react application with all the necessary files included.

```
npx --ignore-existing create-react-app reactproject
```

Just navigate to your G: drive in your terminal and then run the above like this:

```
> cd G:
> npx --ignore-existing create-react-app reactproject
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem a couple of minutes ago.

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app 
$ create-react-app my-react-app
$ cd my-react-app
$ npm start
```

Happy Hacking!